# Android - How combining Shape drwable and text color different states for button?

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, textcolor

I have some troubles managing Android State List for a button. I specified some Shape drwable item for different states, but i also need to change textColor depending on the current state.

My actual state list xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/white"
                android:endColor="@color/light_gray"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/classic_red1" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/classic_red1"
                android:endColor="@color/classic_red2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I need also to change textColor based on these 2 states.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26):

selector for the button BG:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor="@color/light_gray"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/classic_red1" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>

</item>

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#424242" />  //another custom shape here for focus state
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/classic_red1"
            android:endColor="@color/classic_red2"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

selector for the button text color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/black" /> <!-- default/unchecked -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Aaargh!! What a fool.. I thought of having to put all in the background drawable resource. Many thanks!

Comment: and the BG selector is a xml under the drawable directory, where the text color one is a xml under the color directory - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743584/how-to-set-the-text-style-of-a-button-in-selectors