# How to set the text style of a button in selectors?

Tags: android, button

Button selectors allows to define a background for each state of the button, but how can the button's text style be defined for each state? My objective is to grey out a button when disabled. So I set a greyed out background to the disable state of the button, but the only way I found to also grey out the text is to change it's color dynamically when I disable the button...

Anybody can help?

Thanks

```
<style name="srp_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item> <!-- How to specify different color for different state? -->
    <!-- more stuff -->
</style>
```

**drawable/btn_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/pink" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape>
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Please put your Code which you have tried...

Comment: Just wonder how do you compile <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default</item> without any compilation error. I got No resource found that matches the given name at 'android:background' with value '@drawable/btn_default'.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well!

You can define the Text color for all 4 state, similarly as you defined background for the `Button`. For example:

file name: `/res/color/text_color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#440000"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#004400"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000044"/>
    <item android:color="#444"/> 
</selector>
```

Take this file into your `Button` Style like this:

```
<style name="srp_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item> <!-- Here is specified text color -->
</style>
```

Comment: Wow, it's cool! The attribute "android:color" in a selector's item is undocumented! But it really works!

Comment: here is the docu for it
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning textColor and especially your comment next to it (!-- Here is specified text color -->). I didn't know you can use a normal color selector (with android:color attributes) for textColor as well, and that you can use custom background and custom textColor at the same time. I was googling and reading on Internet for half an hour on how to use text color for the disabled state when you have a custom background (I have a ripple background), I didn't find anything apart from this! Thanks!