# Android: textColor of disabled button in selector not showing?

Tags: android, xml, button, selector, background-image

I am trying to make a button with a selector my button can have the following states:

- Enabled/Disabled
- Pressed/Not Pressed

According to the states mentioned above. I need to manipulate the button's:

- Text color
- background image

The button starts off my being disabled so it should have the disabled textColor and the disabled button background. But I can see the default textColor (specified in style) and NO background image!

Here is my selector button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:textColor="#9D9FA2"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />    

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:textColor="#9D9FA2"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>

    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>    

</selector>
```

And here is my button declaration in the my layout.xml

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/reserve_button"
        android:text="@string/reserve_button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

And finally this is my style (where my default textColor is set)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <resources>

     <style name="buttonStyle">
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#282780</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
     </style>

</resources>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You need to also create a [`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for text colors identifying different states.

Do the following:

1. Create another XML file in `res\color` named something like `text_color.xml`.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <!-- disabled state -->
     <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#9D9FA2" /> 
     <item android:color="#000"/>
   </selector>
   ```
2. In your `style.xml`, put a reference to that `text_color.xml` file as follows:

   ```
   <style name="buttonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
   </style>
   ```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: don't you need to save your text_color.xml file in /res/drawable (rather than /res/color) if you refer to it by @drawable/text_color ?

Comment: @Erwan thanks for correction. actually if you see the edit history, I posted it as drawable folder, and some nice guy edited it to color but forgot to update it to `@color` in buttyStyle. Now its updated.

Comment: `text_color.xml` does not compile (for me, at least) unless I place it in the `drawable` folder, which the requires referring to it as `@drawable/text_color`

Comment: @mickey yes, you are correct, so if you see the edit history, it was initially suggested in drawable, but someone updated it to color folder, I've now rectified it.

Comment: @AdilSoomro just tried it, for me it only works when it's in `@color/text_color.xml`. You have it set correctly in your other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743584/how-to-set-the-text-style-of-a-button-in-selectors. I updated your answer.

Comment: @D3LIC1OU5 if you look at the comments, both ways have been told to work. I just consulted documentation and `color` is correct folder for [Color State List Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) Your edit is welcome.

Comment: To set the color state list programmatically, you need to use something like this: `button.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(resources, R.drawable.text_color, null));` Note you can put the text_color.xml file in `res/drawables` instead of `res/color`.

Comment: I didn't have to define the style. I could reference selector directly from the button's textColor. sdk 27

Comment: @Armai yes, however style is helpful in applying same theme to multiple screen or many buttons. So you change from one place and it applies to all buttons/screens.

Answer (score 12):

1.Create a color folder in /res/ folder and in color folder create on xml:

text_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- disabled state --> 
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#776678" /> 
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/>
</selector>
```

2.Now Create a xml layout:

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button_search"
     android:layout_width="652dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:text="Hello Bhaskar"
     android:textColor="@color/text_color_selector"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

The most easy solution is to set color filter to the background image of and button as I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485854/1918752)

You can do as follow:

```
if ('need to set button disable')
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
else
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
```

Hope I helped someone...

Comment: This is a nice way to do this dynamically, when you don't have the button background image in advance. But this doesn't take care of the text color.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a color list

**file location:**

```
res/color/filename.xml
```

The filename will be used as the resource ID.

**resource reference:**

In Java: `R.color.filename`

In XML: `@[package:]color/filename`

**syntax:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="hex_color"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

**Example:**

XML file saved at `res/color/button_text.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This layout XML will apply the color list to a View:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

Refer: [Color List Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource)

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/reserve_button"
        android:text="@string/reserve_button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

I cannot see diabling of your button in your layout xml. add this to your button layout.

```
android:enabled="false"
```

so your Button layout will be,

```
<Button android:id="@+id/reserve_button"
        android:text="@string/reserve_button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

Comment: @ Aqif Hamid I do that programatically button.setEnabled(false) in my onCreat() method