# how to customize the android spinner?

Tags: android, xml, spinner, android-spinner, android-xml

Hi guys i have looked at various sites on how to customize the spinner but they have been poor and have not helped me to achieve the look i want. So i have tried to use the rules of customizing a button to help. Here is my code

spinner

```
   <Spinner
                     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                      android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scannershape"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
     />
```

background of spinner

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#fafafa"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#fafafa"
        android:angle="360"/>
    <padding android:left="6dp"
        android:top="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />



    <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#cfcfcf" />

</shape>
```

The look is almost perfect but there are a few things missing.

1,First of all with the normal spinner when it is clicked there is a brief moment when the scanner turns bright orange to show you have clicked it. How do i do this in my customization as it no longer does this anymore in my customized version? and if possible but not important change this color to orange.
2, Secondly the normal spinner has a arrow that points downward to indicate a dropdown list. This is also lost in my customization. How do i customize this arrow into my spinner?

finally were is this file located so i can see if the answers to my question might be there?

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
```

Comment: It's [here](http://www.google.com). ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may use selector. There's a [question for buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225166/android-textcolor-of-disabled-button-in-selector-not-showing), it's the same for spinner, I think