# styles and Buttons

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles

i have made a style for the button to be seen in a "bolding" way.
but when i use the `setEnabled(false)` and `setClickable(false)` it make the button disabled but i can't see it because i am using a style , so how can i make the button more like "into" (as if it is clicked) when i use set Enable(false) ???

code:

```
signin.setClickable(false);
signin.setEnabled(false);
```

I don't want to discard the style but to modify it but i don't know how.

style:

```
 <style name="btnStyleShakespeare" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
   <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
   <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
   <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
   <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
   <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.6</item>
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_btn_shakespeare</item>
   <item name="android:padding">10dip</item>
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: show your style code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another XML file in res\color named something like text_color.xml (based on [Adil Soomro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593709/adil-soomro)'s [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11225530)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- disabled state -->
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#000000" /> 
  <item android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

In your style.xml, replace

```
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom selector list which will be set as your button background.
Something like: 
`btnSelector.xml` in your `/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- when button is pressed (touched/clicked) -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When button is disabled, i.e clickable and enabled is set to false -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>  
      <!-- Default, when button is clickable -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

And you will have 3 different drawables each for clicked/pressed state, disabled state and normal state.
Then in your custom style change:

@drawable/btnSelector.xml