# Can't change button disabled color

Tags: java, android, button

I have a custom style that I have defined on a button but I can't seem to be able to define the button disabled color. It shows up as the colorButtonNormal which I don't want.

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/buttonPressed</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonMain</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas??

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: textColor of disabled button in selector not showing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225166/android-textcolor-of-disabled-button-in-selector-not-showing)