# Save text color in android

Tags: android

I have a TextView in a layout, on click of text I want to changed the color, I know I can use `text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));` but the problem is that the color does not save and after pressing back the color does not get changed, what can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a selector to you `textView`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

or you can register `ontouchlistener` on you `button` 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

and with help of the MotionEvent you can make switch case of the actions for when you are pressing and when you are releasing the button

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Answer (score 3):

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:state_pressed="true"
  android:color="#ffffffff"/> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
  android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000"/>  <!--default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: it causes this error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.selector in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.emergencycalls-1.apk]`

Comment: @something u r missing to use

Comment: tell me what exactly u r doing?

Comment: it seys item tag needs drawable

Comment: add  above xml file to u r texview android:drawable="@drawable/xmlfilename"

Comment: clean the project once and check

Answer (score 0):

Well!

You can define the Text color for all 4 state, similarly as you defined background for the Button. For example:

file name: /res/color/text_color.xml

XML file saved at res/drawable/button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#440000"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#004400"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000044"/>
<item android:color="#444"/> 
</selector>
```

Take this file into your Button Style(\res\values\styles.xml) like this:

```
<style name="button_text" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
 <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color.xml</item> <!-- Here is specified text color --   >
</style>
```

Now add this style to your button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/button_text">
</Button>
```

For detail check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743584/how-to-set-the-text-style-of-a-button-in-selectors)

Comment: I want to change the text color not setting a background, in first solution your code needs an image as background

Comment: @AmirSadeghsorry i miss understood the question, now I have updated the answer .I'll surely help u