# android:textColorHighlight for android Switch not working

Tags: android, android-layout, switch-statement, background-color

I need to change the color of both side in android switch button. I tried with `android:textColorHighlight` in my xml file but it seems not work. This is my code:

```
 <Switch
                android:id="@+id/sdrt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:textOff="0"
                android:textOn="1" />
```

How could I change the background color of both selected and un-selected buttons in android switch?

Comment: see  this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140801/1765530

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, the textColorHighlight would not change the background color of your button. You can use style to set the background color of your button.

Please refer to [How to set the text style of a button in selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743584/how-to-set-the-text-style-of-a-button-in-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Looksl ike a bug.  you have to call myTextView.setHighlightColor(Color.RED); for example in code...seems to not work when called from xml